# Is it possible to add calendar control in boundfield inside grdview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a problem in updating date using gridview. I want to add ajax control toolkit calendar control inside the gridview boundfield.

My sample gridview will look like this. these gridview details are from table.so, my **Date** column in **BOUNDFIELD**

[image]

when I update date, I need ajax calendar control should pop up to select date.

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Item Templates......

**Example :**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("YourValue").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>

     // Add your item here (Like Textbox With Caleder control)

 </EditItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: nice one which I expected.